# How to get interests from public user pages?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I try to get public interests from user pages by link https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/interests?access_key=...
But I always receive empty 'data' array, when I request data from non-friend user.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get data from users besides their name, id, gender, and picture that you are not friends with via the Graph API.

Comment: I'm just giving you the answer. If you want the data, you will need to break the Facebook Terms of Service and scrape the data because you won't be able to get it via the graph api.